# How to handle actions from context menu of a QLineEdit in Qt?

Tags: qt, contextmenu, qwidget, qlineedit

I would like to intercept the paste action of a QLineEdit context menu that is created by default in any QLineEdit widget (see picture below)

[image]

Is there a way to redirect the Paste action of the context menu by any means?

Comment: What do you mean by redirect ?, that the text of paste is different.

Comment: @eyllansec I generally want to intercept the event and handle the data differently.

Answer (score 2):

One can fiddle with the actions in the context menu by overloading the [contextMenuEvent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlineedit.html#contextMenuEvent) of the QLineEdit widget.

**Edit**:

The code of the link above:

```
void LineEdit::contextMenuEvent(QContextMenuEvent *event)
{
    QMenu *menu = createStandardContextMenu();
    menu->addAction(tr("My Menu Item"));
    //...
    menu->exec(event->globalPos());
    delete menu;
}
```

And the code that I actually used for my purposes:

```
menu = self.createStandardContextMenu()

menu.actions()[5].connect(self.paste) # The hard ref to the 6th item is not ideal but what can you do...

menu.exec_(event.globalPos())
```

Comment: You could also use `createStandardContextMenu()`:  `void LineEdit::contextMenuEvent(QContextMenuEvent *event)
{
    QMenu *menu  = createStandardContextMenu();
    QAction *action  = menu->exec(event->globalPos());

    if(action->text().compare("&Paste\tCtrl+V") == 0){
        qDebug()<<"test";
    }

}`

Comment: @eyllanesc That is correct. Out of completeness I edited my answer to show the complete code.

Comment: A better way to handle connecting the action would be to create an action first, connect it's 'triggered' slot and then add it into the menu. This also allows you to index it into the context menu wherever you want. I proposed an edit to your post :)